# Firebase API key is undefined when moved to environment variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, heroku, environment-variables

I am moving from localhost to a Heroku hosted application, and in order to commit my credentials.js file and keep API keys secret, I replaced each value with a `process.env` variable in credentials.js before commiting the file to GitHub. Now I'm getting an error that states: `Error: Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.`

I have confirmed that the correct API key was set as an environment variable, and to check, I added a `console.log("firebaseApiKey  " + credentials.firebaseApiKey)` and it returns `undefined`.

This *seems* like an issue that could be common, but I haven't found a fix yet by Googling. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: I am having a similar problem when moving variables to a .env file. The app works but I get the same error as above in my tests. A new console did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't changed to a new command prompt window. It works now.